# Finding information about terminated instance in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I want to find information about a terminated instance in BizTalk 2010 - where can I look for that information? Specifically, I'm looking for information about an instance for one application.

Answer (score 2):

You might start up the BizTalk Administration Console and go to the BizTalk Group node.
Then, on the page thats pops up, select 'Tracked Service Instances'.

Given the fact that you are tracking the specific instance you want to find, you might be able to find this by extending the query with "State" equals "Terminated".

Depending if you tracked it or not AND how long ago it was AND how long your tracking is kept in the DTA database (see the SQL jop parameters for that), you will find what you are looking for.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do this as step one and then combine this with the answer of boatseller and you have a complete answer.  1) Find it 2) Look at the properties of the terminated instance, like Message Flow, Tracked Message Events and for Orchestrations you also have the Orchestration Debugger to look at the flow.

Answer (score 0):

Specifics notwithstanding, all available information about any instance can be viewed in BizTalk Administrator through the context (right click) options.

The only other place you may find relevant information is in the Event Viewer if there was a previous error.

There is no special database-only log or other source of information.